# Java or C# for License Plate Recognition System?

Tags: c#, java, image-processing

Im doing a license plate recognition system as my final year project. As I have no experience in image processing before I'm a bit confused about which programming platform to use. Can you please tell out of Java and C# which will support well.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: See if you can find a .NET library for [the Amazon Mechanical Turk](http://aws.amazon.com/mturk/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. Implement an ANPR engine from scratch. Most likely it would take more than two months.
2. Use [JavaANPR](http://javaanpr.sourceforge.net/), or port it to C# if .NET is a must for you.
3. Employ the evaluation version of an already existing ANPR SDK such as www.arhungary.hu, x.htsol.com/index.php , www.warelogic.com , ... . There are literally hundreds of them.

   I would probably pick option 2.

Answer (score 4):

I advise C# because of [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which is a cross platform .Net wrapper to the Intel OpenCV image processing library. Allowing OpenCV functions to be called from .NET compatible languages such as C#, VB, VC++, IronPython etc. The wrapper can be compiled in Mono and run on Linux / Mac OS X.

If you are familiar with C++ use OpenCV directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do image processing, but have little time for your project, and since you are  a student, your **best bet** would be to use MATLAB for the image processing related computations (at least). In your University's library there must be quite a few books with plenty of examples about these problems and how to solve them with MATLAB (besides the huge  online documentation from Mathworks.com).

If you still want to use Java or .NET, it would be easier to use them only for the User Interface, and let the processing engine be in MATLAB.
(Just take a look at many toolboxes MATLAB has, e.g. the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/), [Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neuralnet/), [Fuzzy Logic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/fuzzylogic/), etc. )

Comment: I do have 2 months to implement it. My supervisor is not much happy, about using matlab, cos he thinks then the challenge is less. I'l have to select one out of Java and .NET. 
BTW Thanks for ur comment.

Comment: @hp87: Than do what I did for my final project: except the GUI, I did the simulations and algorithm development and prototyping in Matlab (mostly for myself, and to see if it really works how I imagined it), and than simply translated them to Java :) (well it's not that simple, but much much simpler than to make them directly in Java - at least it was for me).

Comment: oh thats a good idea. Didnt think something like that before :)